# What are the exact differences between the Nintendo Gamecube and Panasonic Q?

Tags: version-differences, nintendo-gamecube

I have been reading recently that there is a version of the Nintendo Gamecube that was exclusive to Japan called the Panasonic Q.

What are the exact differences between the Japan exclusive Panasonic Q and the NTSC-U/PAL version of the Gamecube?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did my own research about this because I knew that DVD Playback was not the only improvement. The new features and/or improvements introduced in the Panasonic Q compared to the GameCube are:

- RCA and S-Video outputs are present instead of the Analog AV Out port
- Uses a 100V [C7/C8 connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C7/C8_coupler) for power instead of the standard Gamecube AC Adapter

[image]
[image]

- Is significantly bigger, due to the new internal components required for DVD Playback
- The disc mechanism is Tray-loading (a tray goes out and you put the disc there) instead of the Top-loading (the top of the device is opened for the disc) of the Gamecube

[image]

- The Controller Ports have a Blue Light so they are easier to find in the dark
- A LCD Display that shows the current mode of the device (DVD and GAMECUBE)
- A new set of audio enhancement profiles: Dialog Enhancer, Cinema, Surround and Bass Plus (useable on both DVD and Gamecube mode)

[image]

- Due to the size changes, a new Game Boy Player was released for the Panasonic Q

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Panasonic Q was just a GameCube with a built in DVD player, which original GameCube lacked.

> The Panasonic Q (also known as Q and GameQ) is a hybrid version of the GameCube with a **DVD player** manufactured by Panasonic in cooperation with Nintendo. The system was officially released only in Japan. A feature of its main competitors Xbox and PlayStation 2, **the GameCube lacked commercial DVD movie playback** functionality due to the use of the Nintendo optical discs format for games and the correspondingly small disc tray.

(emphasis mine)
[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panasonic_Q)