# Are there any differences when it comes to playing PS2 Content in the PSX? What about unsupported features?

Tags: version-differences, ps2

The [PSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSX_(digital_video_recorder)) (not to be confused with the PS1) was a Japanese exclusive DVR that it came with a PlayStation 2 inside of it, kinda like the [Nintendo Gamecube inside of the Panasonic Q DVD](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/358550), also exclusive to the Japanese market.

When it comes to using the PSX as a PS2:

- Are there any differences in the use of the PS2 features? (game startup, Memory Card data management, etc)
- Are there some PS2 features that are unsupported on the PSX? (the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSX_(digital_video_recorder)) says that HDD games are sported like FFXI, but nothing about accessories and other software)